# How to set multiple permissions in one class view, depending on http request

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I am working with django-rest-framework. The problem I am having is that the url is identical for both the POST and the GET methods but I want to have different permissions depending on which method is being called.  Right now I'm using class based views and I can't figure out how to set different permissions depending on the method.  What I want is if the user is an admin that they both POST and GET, if the user is authenticated than they can only GET, and if the user isn't authenticated they can't do anything.

```
class CategoryList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = QuestionCategory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionCategorySerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
```

Answer (score 7):

Just an update.

You can override 'get_permissions' instead of 'get_queryset'.

For example:

```
def get_permissions(self):
    if self.request.method == 'GET':
        return [permissions.AllowAny()]
    elif self.request.method == 'DELETE':
        return [permissions.IsAdminUser()]
    else:  # PUT, PATCH
        return [...]
```

Note that 'get_permission' returns a list of permission instances, not classes.

Answer (score 2):

You could write it in a function to override default function to realize this.

use `self.request` to do this

```
class CategoryList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = QuestionCategorySerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        # this function used to get queryset
        # override this to judge request method

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            self.permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)

        return QuestionCategory.objects.all()
```

**get_queryset:** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset

And you can write a `get` or `post` method in your `generic view`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-singleobjectmixin-with-view

Comment: That seems to be what I would want to use but my code is never hitting the get_context_data

Comment: The code will hit `get_context_data`, `get_queryset` such functions automatically, you just need override them

Comment: Depending on the user type (anonym, user, staff/admin) I set a different serializer class using your method. This is nice! So I can easily respond with more or less sensible information depending on the user type. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

i know this is is late to the party - but I recently had to figure out the same thing and found very little help in the docs or on the interwebs. this is what i eventually came up with -- hope it helps someone else who might have the same problem:

```
from request_admin.models import Rep
from request_admin.serializers import RepSerializer

from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework import mixins

from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class RepList(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                     mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                     generics.GenericAPIView):
    paginate_by = 10
    queryset = Rep.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RepSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        if request.user.is_authenticated() == False:
            raise PermissionDenied

        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

here is the django doc for [user objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User)

here is the django doc for [exceptions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/exceptions/)

here is the django doc for [mixins](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#mixins)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it in 2024:

In my situation, I had to manage various permissions not only based on the HTTP method but also tailored to specific endpoints. So I created a generic permission class that does it for any endpoint.

view.py:

```
class ProductStatusListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    ...
    permission_classes = [DynamicPermission]
    http_permission_mapper =  {
        'GET': 'can_view_products',
        'POST': 'can_add_products',
        'PUT': 'can_update_products',
        'DELETE': 'can_delete_products'
            
    }
```

permissions.py:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

class DynamicPermission(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        permission_code = view.http_permission_mapper.get(request.method)
        return request.user.user_permissions.filter(
                    permission_code=permission_code
               ).exists()
```